# 3d manipulator not on object, stuck in scene center

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-manipulator

Whenever I move an object by the transform manipulator in the 3d view, it disappears when I hold it (like normal) but when I let go, the arrows haven't followed the object. It just sits in the center of the scene no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the **Pivot Point** for rotation and scaling is set to *3D Cursor*. In this mode the 3D manipulator, i.e. the movement arrows, is also placed at the 3D Cursor.

[image: pivot point]

Setting the pivot point to something like *Active Element* will also move the 3D manipulator to the origin of the active object.

Alternatively, depending on your intentions, you can move the 3D cursor, for example to the active object by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and selecting *Snap Cursor to Active*.

Answer (score 1):

Hit the <kbd>.</kbd> (fullstop, period key) on your keyboard to get the *Pivot* menu.

You can also find the menu top middle of the screen next to the *Snapping* menu.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but for anyone who has this issue, you can also try checking:

Object > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry

This fixed the issue for me. The other two solutions did not work for me for whatever reason.